# Receive RTSP stream within docker container

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to decode a camera rtsp stream using ffmpeg_libs within a ubuntu docker container. The ffmpeg debug output seems to show that it successfully negotiates the rtsp-digest authentication (ie. RTSP/1.0 200 OK), and receives an SPS (nalu 7) and PPS (nalu 8), but nothing after that. It times out, retries, etc. That doesn’t really make sense to me.

The same code compiled and run locally (not in docker) works fully.

Also, if I decode a file, the code works fine both locally and in docker container. So, the basic ffmpeg_lib decode is working. The difficulty is with the stream interface running in docker.

Is there additional authentication through the docker interface, or maybe port access, or something? I’m not much of a networking guy, so I’m really lost at this point.

The ffmpeg logs is below, and my docker run command is:

```
docker run -it --name VideoRx videorx:latest (also tried with -p 554)
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks,
Wayne

```
avformat_version(): 3756900  Build: 3756900  Ident: Lavf57.83.100
avformat_open_input(): rtsp://admin:public_pwd@192.168.1.237
Probing rtsp score:100 size:0
[tcp @ 0x56263b430a20] No default whitelist set
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] Sending:
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.237:554 RTSP/1.0

... [snipped]
Initial authentication handshake (OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP).
All success, server replies: 'RTSP/1.0 200 OK'
....

[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] Sending:
PLAY rtsp://192.168.1.237:554/ RTSP/1.0
Range: npt=0.000-
CSeq: 5
User-Agent: Lavf57.83.100
Session: 420467284
Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="IP Camera(C1003)", nonce="129b254c8da4e0ffb530f64f79938bcd", uri="rtsp://192.168.1.237:554/", response="82c6c0f1fadea3739846866e8e50e855"

--
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] line='RTSP/1.0 200 OK' 
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] line='CSeq: 5'
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] line='Session:        420467284'
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] line='RTP-Info: url=rtsp://192.168.1.237:554/trackID=1;seq=43938;rtptime=4022155312'
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] line='Date:  Thu, Aug 02 2018 15:53:00 GMT'
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] line=''
avformat_open_input(): Success erc: 0
avformat_find_stream_info()
[h264 @ 0xaddr2] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0xaddr2] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP 
[rtsp @ 0xaddr1] ...
... Stalls waiting for additional packets
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old but did you manage something with this ?
I'm struggling with the same issue :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I never got this resolved, and then had to move on to other work.  I am still very interested in a solution and willing to help debug.  But, my test camera and gear is at the office while we're home during this covid-19 period.  Please keep me posted if I can help.  I also asked on the Docker forum with no response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
For what it's worth, I finally got my system docker container/camera working by opening a TCP socket in my container to receive the stream instead of an UDP.
It should be working on UDP but for a reason I don't get it doesn't :/

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work on your case :(

Did you try with --network=host ?

Comment: Yes, I recall trying several things related to this,  --network=bridge, host, etc. and some options to specify ports and whatever I could find (it's been a while).  Unfortunately, none solved my problem, so I missed something.  Thanks for the thought.

Comment: We struggled with this to no end when I worked at a large TV/Video streaming company. Last I heard, Docker just does not handle Multicast/UDP, period. We had some pretty good workaround, but they all involved a session, like TCP as you mentioned above.